# Normal JSON to Bigquery JSON requirement separated by newline

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I have a list of dictionaries with a length of more than 100,000+.

How will I be able to convert this in JSON and write it in a JSON file following the requirement of Bigquery to create a JSON file with a newline.

```
{"id":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","dob":"1968-01-22","addresses":[{"status":"current","address":"123 First Avenue","city":"Seattle","state":"WA","zip":"11111","numberOfYears":"1"},{"status":"previous","address":"456 Main Street","city":"Portland","state":"OR","zip":"22222","numberOfYears":"5"}]}
{"id":"2","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","dob":"1980-10-16","addresses":[{"status":"current","address":"789 Any Avenue","city":"New York","state":"NY","zip":"33333","numberOfYears":"2"},{"status":"previous","address":"321 Main Street","city":"Hoboken","state":"NJ","zip":"44444","numberOfYears":"3"}]}
```

instead of

```
[{"id":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","dob":"1968-01-22","addresses":[{"status":"current","address":"123 First Avenue","city":"Seattle","state":"WA","zip":"11111","numberOfYears":"1"},{"status":"previous","address":"456 Main Street","city":"Portland","state":"OR","zip":"22222","numberOfYears":"5"}]}, {"id":"2","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","dob":"1980-10-16","addresses":[{"status":"current","address":"789 Any Avenue","city":"New York","state":"NY","zip":"33333","numberOfYears":"2"},{"status":"previous","address":"321 Main Street","city":"Hoboken","state":"NJ","zip":"44444","numberOfYears":"3"}]}]
```

Notice the difference between two JSON: The first one is newline seperated while the second one is comma seperated (Normal JSON dumping in Python). I need the first one.

What I did before is in the last part of loop, I am doing this:

```
while condition:
     with open('cache/name.json', 'a') as a:
          json_data = json.dumps(store)
          a.write(json_data + '\n')
```

Doing this, I am opening and writing base on the length of list of dictionaries which makes the loop slow.

How will I be able to insert this in a faster way following the requirement of bigquery?

Comment: Hi @Arci M, if you find my answer helpful, please consider accepting/upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format is called NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON and bigquery has inbuilt libraries to load it. Considering you have the json in gs bucket, here is what you may use :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.json"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    table_id,
    location="US",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
    job_config=job_config,
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```